# Does PdfFormXObject cause lines to be lost in itext7?

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, itext7

Using itext7, when I enlarge the page size of a pdf file, I found that it caused the loss of elements outside the visible range. Code below.

```
string cardPdf = "card.pdf";float cardWidth = 266.5f;float cardHeight = 164.4f;
using (PdfDocument cardDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(cardPdf)))
using (Document doc = new Document(cardDoc))
{
    PdfPage page = cardDoc.AddNewPage(new iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize(cardWidth, cardHeight));
    Paragraph carePara = new Paragraph("CARD").SetFontSize(5f);
    doc.Add(carePara);

    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    canvas.SetFillColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY);
    canvas.SetStrokeColor(ColorConstants.BLACK);
    canvas.SetLineWidth(1f);
    canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, cardWidth - 0.1f, cardHeight);
    canvas.SetLineWidth(0.1f);

    //Draw lines outside page visible area
    canvas.MoveTo(0f, -10f);
    canvas.LineTo(cardWidth, -10f);//----> a_line
    canvas.MoveTo(0f, cardHeight + 10f);
    canvas.LineTo(cardWidth, cardHeight + 10f);//----> b_line
    canvas.Stroke();
}
//to enlarge pdf
using (PdfDocument destPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("enlarged.pdf")))
using (PdfDocument sourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(cardPdf)))
{
    var page = destPdf.AddNewPage(new PageSize(cardWidth+40f,cardHeight+40f));
    PdfFormXObject pageCopy = sourcePdf.GetFirstPage().CopyAsFormXObject(destPdf);
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    canvas.AddXObjectAt(pageCopy,20f, 20f);//a_line and b_line are missing
}
```

Does PdfFormXObject cause lines to be lost?
Is there any way to get the full page?

Comment: A form XObject has a bounding box attribute. When iText copies a page as form XObject, it sets that attribute so that it matches the crop box of the page, i.e. the visible page area. If you want that changed, either change the crop box or the page before copying or the bounding box of the resulting form XObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following mkl's replay, the code below got me what I wanted.

```
//to enlarge pdf
using (PdfDocument destPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("enlarged.pdf")))
using (PdfDocument sourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(cardPdf)))
{

    var page = destPdf.AddNewPage(new PageSize(cardWidth+40f,cardHeight+40));
    var oriPage = sourcePdf.GetFirstPage();
    var crop = oriPage.GetCropBox();
    //set a new cropbox
    oriPage.SetCropBox(new Rectangle(crop.GetX(), crop.GetY()-20f, crop.GetWidth(), crop.GetHeight()+40f));
    PdfFormXObject pageCopy = oriPage.CopyAsFormXObject(destPdf);
    
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    canvas.AddXObjectAt(pageCopy,20f, 0f);
}
```